# How to Switch an If/Else to a For Loop?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, if-statement

I'm doing a save button where users can pick a selected date and an array of times then save their selections. Users can pick up to three dates and array of times, then save each selection. However, is there a better way to reduce code duplication from my if/else statement? Thanks.

```
@objc func handleSaveDateAndTimes() {
        
    guard let selectedDay = selectedDay else { return }
        
    if selectedCardViewCount == 0 {
        selectedViews[0].view?.isHidden = false
        selectedViews[0].selectedDate = selectedDay
        viewModel.selectedDate = "\(selectedDay.month.month)-\(selectedDay.day)-\(selectedDay.month.year)"
        viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = timeChoiceArray
        daySelectionLabel.text = "1/3"
    } else if selectedCardViewCount == 1 {
        selectedViews[1].view?.isHidden = false
        selectedViews[1].selectedDate = selectedDay
        viewModel.selectedDate = "\(selectedDay.month.month)-\(selectedDay.day)-\(selectedDay.month.year)"
        viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = timeChoiceArray
        daySelectionLabel.text = "2/3"
    } else {
        selectedViews[2].view?.isHidden = false
        selectedViews[2].selectedDate = selectedDay
        viewModel.selectedDate = "\(selectedDay.month.month)-\(selectedDay.day)-\(selectedDay.month.year)"
        viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = timeChoiceArray
        daySelectionLabel.text = "3/3"
    }
        
    selectedCardViewCount += 1
    continueButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
    continueButton.isEnabled = true
        
}
```

Comment: Isn't `viewModel.selectedDate = ...; viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = ;` the same code? That can be put after. That's one. For the rest, it's a little more facto work.

Comment: When I print those, it changes per save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it without a loop like this

```
@objc func handleSaveDateAndTimes() {

    guard let selectedDay = selectedDay else { return }

    selectedViews[selectedCardViewCount].view?.isHidden = false
    selectedViews[selectedCardViewCount].selectedDate = selectedDay
    viewModel.selectedDate = "\(selectedDay.month.month)-\(selectedDay.day)-\(selectedDay.month.year)"
    viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = timeChoiceArray

    selectedCardViewCount += 1
    daySelectionLabel.text = "\(selectedCardViewCount )/3"

    continueButton.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
    continueButton.isEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: The selectedViews[0] won't work because it doesn't recognize the selectedCardViewCount is being added to. Everything else works though

Comment: @ZacharySmouse sorry, I did miss that. I’ll fix my answer to correct it.

Comment: It's not specified by the user, but the `else` case might suggest it's possible, but what happen if this method is called 4 times? `selectedViews[selectedCardViewCount]` might be wrong (and even triggers an out of bound error)

Comment: @Larme you are correct, adding code to ensure no runtime errors is always a good idea in cases where you don’t know what you don’t know. Your answer is certainly a good one and had it been posted and I had seen it I wouldn’t have bothered posting mine.

Answer (score 2):

Your if/else could be factorized like that:

```
let index = selectedCardViewCount > 1 ? 2 : selectedCardViewCount
let selectedView = selectedViews[index]
selectedView.view?.isHidden = false
viewModel.selectedDate = "\(selectedDay.month.month)-\(selectedDay.day)-\(selectedDay.month.year)"
viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = timeChoiceArray     
daySelectionLabel.text = "\(index+1)/3"
```

Some explaination:

I see that

```
viewModel.selectedDate = "\(selectedDay.month.month)-\(selectedDay.day)-\(selectedDay.month.year)"
viewModel.selectTimesOfDay = timeChoiceArray
```

Are the same each time.

Then, I see :

```
if selectedCardViewCount == aValue {
    selectedViews[aValue].view?.isHidden = false
    selectedViews[aValue].selectedDate = selectedDay
    daySelectionLabel.text = "aValue+1/3"
} else if selectedCardViewCount == anotherValue {
    selectedViews[anotherValue].view?.isHidden = false
    selectedViews[anotherValue].selectedDate = selectedDay
    daySelectionLabel.text = "anotherValue+1/3"
} else {
    selectedViews[2].view?.isHidden = false
    selectedViews[2].selectedDate = selectedDay
    daySelectionLabel.text = "3/3"
}
```

And anotherValue is aValue + 1.

So it's the `selectedCardViewCount` value, except that it can be superior to 2. (I don't know if it can be bigger, but I made it safe) with `let index = selectedCardViewCount > 1 ? 2 : selectedCardViewCount`
Then I just reuse that value.